# Wordpress rewrite with custom parameter doesn't work

Tags: wp-query, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm currently developing a plugin which takes a parameter from URL (example: `example.com/product_id/1234` is converted to `example.com`) and passes it in WP_Query (supposedly this should be used instead of GET or POST) for later use. My code so far looks like this:

```
function shortcode_callback() {
    echo get_query_var('product_id','not found<br>');
}

function prepare_rewrite() {
    add_filter('query_vars','rewrite_add_var');
    add_rewrite_rule('^product_id/([^/]*)/?$','index.php?page_id=18&product_id=$matches[1]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

function rewrite_add_var($q_vars) {
    $q_vars[] = 'product_id';
    return $q_vars;
}

add_action('init','prepare_rewrite');
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode_callback');
```

Unfortuantely, even though redirect works, the custom parameter does not exist. I've been trying to put this piece of code in `functions.php` file, but to no avail. I've been also trying to solve this issue by using add_rewrite_tag, but as far as I can tell it's only useful when it comes to post selection.

Comment: Jan, have you tried to dump all public query_vars in order to verify yours is actually registered as one? I'd try moving the line `add_filter('query_vars', 'rewrite_add_var');`out of the `prepare_rewrite()` function just to verify you have not missed the moment for filtering the query vars.

Comment: @vlood Yes, I dump query vars every time, but parameter product_id doesn't exist. I've listened to your advice and moved `add_filter` out of the function, but the parameter is still missing.

Comment: Ok, could you try this instead:

Add this code to the beginning of `prepare_rewrite` function:

```global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var( 'product_id' );```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't work.